# how to stop alertdialog from automatic disappearing

Tags: android, android-dialog

Below is my code to alert the user whenever GPS is off. Here my user has to click on one of the options and move further. But if a user clicks elsewhere on screen other than this alert, this alert disappears. How can I stop this alert dialog from disappearing automatically. help please

```
Builder bd = new AlertDialog.Builder(myTest.this);
    bd.setTitle("Alert");       
    bd.setMessage("GPS is disabled. Do you want to");
    bd.setNegativeButton("Enable GPS", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {              
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                }});            
            bd.setPositiveButton("Close App", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {               
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
                });
    bd.show();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use bd.setCancelable(false).  This will make it so it can only go away by pressing the buttons.